# Where can I find a copy of the manual for Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I ordered the digital edition of ME 3 from Origin. Origin *does* have a 'Download Manual' button for it's games, but when I used it for Mass Effect 3, it downloaded a 1.5 MB Zip file named Manuals. Inside?

There was this:

[image: Siezures!]

23 of those, covering a wide variety of languages.

But no manual. I like to read game manuals because I'm a nerd like that. Where is the manual for ME3? Does it even exist in a digital form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to the in-game manual, I think you're specifically searching for an offline copy.

There's not a paper manual in boxed copies of the game (we just get a printed version of that same epilepsy warning that you've already seen).

However, you can find PDF copies of the Mass Effect 3 manual at EA's [help site](https://help.ea.com/article/mass-effect-3-manuals).  They have digital copies for PS3, Xbox 360, and PC.

Answer (score 9):

Well, I'm not sure if you're specifically after only a clone of a paper manual that may or may not exist, but there's an in-game manual that you can access from the main menu under the Extras section.

[image]

It's also accessible while you're actively playing.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, if I weren't at work I'd have snazzy freehand circled some screen shots and I'd show you!!! :-)

Comment: I'm saving my freehand circles for special occasions!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a full manual inside the game.  From the main options menu (during game play, where you can choose load, save, party) at the top it says "Manual".