# Is there a weak point on an Atlas?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Do they have a weak point? Generally headshots do more damage to enemies, and an Atlas is a pretty fearsome foe. I know using biotic/tech powers can speed up the destruction by chewing through shields and then armor, but is there a particular point on it that I can be aiming for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aiming for the cockpit is the best way to beat an atlas. After you've taken out the mech's shields, you can actually shatter the protective glass, which leaves the pilot exposed and vulnerable.

And once *that* happens, you're only one accurate shot away from...

Comment: Can this be done in multiplayer?

Comment: @aslum I have not yet seen it done, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Lions and tigers and bears! Oh my!

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeeeet

Comment: @aslum No, you can not hijack an Atlas in multiplayer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55979/1770

Answer (score 2):

In the "Enemy Tips" section of the manual (which I found with the help of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53917/16793) post, there's the following advice on fighting Atlus':

> The Atlas is a hulking death machine with powerful armor, shields, and
>   weapons. Shatter the canopy to expose the pilot.

Answer (score 2):

Atlases have multiple weak points.

In Single Player, targetting the cockpit is *very* effective if you're using weapons that have a reasonable chance to shatter it and allow you to hijack the vehicle (Sniper rifles in particular).

If this isn't an option, you'll want to target the plates at the **Knees, Shoulders, and Groin**, which when destroyed, will cause the Atlas to take a large spike of damage, or target the **thrusters** mounted on the Atlas's back, which are a notably soft target, and, better yet, if you're able to shoot at those, the Atlas isn't shooting at you.