# Can you hijack an Atlas in ME3 multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

You can hijack the [Atlas](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Atlas) in ME3 single player. However in multiplayer, it seems like the Atlas will always blow up. Can you hijack it in multiplayer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From that very wiki page:

> Killing the pilot will destroy the Atlas immediately in Multiplayer.

So it would appear that no, you cannot hijack an Atlas in multiplayer.

Comment: I just linked to the wiki page to reference what an Atlas is. Maybe I should actually read it.

Comment: Did NOT know you could do that in single player.

Comment: @mike1987 - supposedly you can, but I always found it hard to take out the driver without actually destroying the atlas.