# What are all the possible power combinations for detonation?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I know that biotic powers can detonate each other if one has a duration, but what about bio/tech combinations or ammo combinations?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found this list of biotic and tech combos on the [Bioware forums.](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-Multiplayer-Discussion-/A-list-of-biotic-and-elemental-tech-combos-9629730-1.html)

### Biotic Combos

- Singularity --> Warp, Throw, Shockwave, Charge, Nova, Cluster Grenade, Reave
- Stasis --> Warp, Throw, Shockwave, Charge, Nova, Cluster Grenade, Reave
- Pull --> Warp, Throw, Shockwave, Charge, Nova, Cluster Grenade, Reave
- Warp --> Throw, Shockwave, Charge, Nova, Cluster Grenade, Reave
- Lift Grenade --> Warp, Throw, Shockwave, Charge, Nova, Cluster Grenade, Reave
- Shockwave (only with Rank 6 Lifting Shockwave evolution) --> Warp, Throw, Charge, Nova, Cluster Grenade, Reave
- Reave --> Warp, Throw, Shockwave, Charge, Nova, Cluster Grenade

### Tech Combos

**FIRE EXPLOSION**
 - Can be set up by: Incinerate, Carnage, Inferno Grenade, Incendiary Ammo

- Can be detonated with any Biotic/Tech/Combat powers that can deal direct damage (except for the powers that are used to set up the combo).
- Effect: Enemies effected by any of the fire based powers, cause an AoE fire explosion, once they are killed by a direct damage power. The effect is similar to blowing up Pyros with Overload in ME2.
- Note: Enemy MUST be killed by the second power, in order to cause a Fire Explosion. E.G. it will not work, if an enemy is hit by Incinerate --> Overload, and still has HP left after that. So, in this case, Overload would have to do sufficient damage to outright kill a burning enemy, in order to cause a Fire Explosion.

**CRYO EXPLOSION**
 - Can be set up by: Cryo Blast, Cryo Ammo

- Can be detonated with any Biotic/Tech/Combat powers that can deal direct damage.
- Effect: Frozen enemies killed by damage based powers, cause an AoE cryo explosion, freezing any enemy that is nearby.
- Note: Same as Fire Explosion, frozen enemies MUST be killed by the second power in order to trigger Cryo Explosion.

**TECH BURST**
 - Can be set up by: Overload, Energy Drain, Disruptor Ammo, Sabotage

- Can be detonated by any Biotic/Tech/Combat powers that can deal direct damage (except for the powers that are used to set up the combo).
- Effect: Enemies effected by electricity based powers, discharge multiple electricity bolts to nearby enemies, when hit with direct damage powers. Effect is similar to Overload's Chain Overload upgrade.
- Note: Unlike Fire & Cryo Explosion combos, this one doesn't require an enemy to be killed by the second power. E.G. enemy hit by Overload --> Incinerate will produce Tech Burst, whether he is killed by Incinerate or not.

Comment: Why did you edit this list? You're missing the Reave combos along with a bunch of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of some of the combinations from the [manual](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53917/16793).

> Biotic Combos: Trigger these by combining more than one biotic effect, such as lifting an enemy with Pull before striking them with Warp. Biotic combos result in
>   an explosion that blasts not just the target, but also the area around
>   the target.
>
> Electric Combos Trigger these by combining an electrical effect with a detonator, such as
>   electrocuting an enemy with Overload before striking them with
>   Concussive Shot. Electric combos result in bonus damage to shields and
>   a chance to stun undefended enemies.
>
> Flame Combos Trigger these by combining a flame effect with a lethal detonator, such
>   as igniting an enemy with Incinerate before finishing them off with
>   Carnage. Flame combos result in bonus damage to armor and a chance
>   to light undefended enemies on fire.
>
> Cryo Combos Trigger these by combining a freeze effect with a lethal detonator, such as
>   freezing an enemy with Cryo Ammo before finishing them off with Biotic
>   Charge. Cryo combos freeze undefended enemies and will chill the rest.