# What is a tech burst and how do you do it in ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the possible power combinations for detonation?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53997/what-are-all-the-possible-power-combinations-for-detonation)

This is probably a silly question but I can't figure this out. I play as an infiltrator, a tech class, and sometimes will kill an enemy with a tech burst. It generally happens in the heat of battle when I not focusing on every single action my team and me do.

What is a tech burst and how do I pull it off?

Comment: Didn't know this was considered a detonation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tech burst is basically an Elemental combo that can be caused by using 2 of the following powers: Overload, Energy Drain, Sabotage and Disruptor Ammo. Tech burst is like other elemental combo attacks, such as Cryo or Fire. To detonate, use any Biotic or Tech combat powers that deal direct damage.
Hope this helps!